# DPDK failed to configure eth device with err No: -22, tx_queues is greater than one (Ethdev port_id=0 nb_tx_queues=2 > 1)

Tags: dpdk

I have an application that uses DPDK for Fast Path. During DPDK initialization, am trying to configure two TX queues for a port, but it failed to configure the eth device.

I am using Intel IGB driver(I350 NIC) on a Bare Metal setup. As per DPDK documentation IGB Poll Mode Driver (https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/igb.html) should support multiple RX/TX queues for a port. Am trying to configure two TX queues for a port(port_id = 0), when invoking the API "*rte_eth_dev_configure(portid = 0, nb_rx_queue = 1, nb_tx_queue = 2, &local_port_conf)*", it is returning error code: -22, "*Ethdev port_id=0 nb_tx_queues=2 > 1*".

Does the IGB PMD driver support multiple TX queues for a port? Or do I need to do any configuration changes to support multiple TX queues?

Comment: Hi Sajesh, can you please share DPDK version, NIC firmware version for better debugging. Please update if you are using PF or VF. what is the test application used to reproduce the error?

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese. The issue got resolved after using PFs.

Comment: good to hear the issue is resolved. From the update it looks like you were using VF which had 1 RX/TX quque. Please use `ethtool` in LINUX to identify the number of queues. In case of DPDK use `dev_get_info` to identify the mx RX and max TX queues. Hence my understanding is there were no check which caused the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel Foundational NIC i350 assign `Up to eight queues per port` for Physical Funtion driver as per `PRODUCT BRIEF Intel® Ethernet Controller I350`. With respect to virtual function per port `1 queue for each VF` with a total of 8 VF max per port defined under `Intel® Ethernet Controller I350 Datasheet`.

In Linux, these can be validated by

1. ethtool: One can check per queue instance with option `-S`, as statistics is supported per queue.
2. dpdk: using `rte_eth_dev_info_get` to get attributes `max_rx_queues and max_tx_queues`

Note: as VF gets allocated with 1 RX-TX queue pair, the error mentioned `-22, Ethdev port_id=0 nb_tx_queues=2 > 1` can be of VF in use. Hence the right way of configuration is first get the DPDK port max rx-tx queues and ensure it is in bounds.

Sample Code Snippet:

```
 /* Initialise each port */
    RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(portid) {
        struct rte_eth_rxconf rxq_conf;
        struct rte_eth_txconf txq_conf;
        struct rte_eth_conf local_port_conf = port_conf;
        struct rte_eth_dev_info dev_info;
        /* skip ports that are not enabled */
        if ((l2fwd_enabled_port_mask & (1 << portid)) == 0) {
            printf("Skipping disabled port %u\n", portid);
            continue;
        }
        nb_ports_available++;
        /* init port */
        printf("Initializing port %u... ", portid);
        fflush(stdout);
        ret = rte_eth_dev_info_get(portid, &dev_info);
        if (ret != 0)
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE,
                "Error during getting device (port %u) info: %s\n",
                portid, strerror(-ret));
        if (dev_info.tx_offload_capa & RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_MBUF_FAST_FREE)
            local_port_conf.txmode.offloads |=
                RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_MBUF_FAST_FREE;

        /* Configure the number of queues for a port. */
        if ((dev_info.max_rx_queues  >= user_rx_queues) && (dev_info.max_tx_queues  >= user_tx_queues)) {
        ret = rte_eth_dev_configure(portid, user_rx_queues, user_tx_queues, &local_port_conf);
        if (ret < 0)
            rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot configure device: err=%d, port=%u\n",
                  ret, portid);
        /* >8 End of configuration of the number of queues for a port. */
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For *virtual functions* (VFs), the NIC model in question supports only single-queue mode ([source](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/main/drivers/net/e1000/igb_ethdev.c#L2305)).

To test multi-queue support, consider passing a *physical function* (PF) to the setup instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response @stackinside and Vipin Varghese. 

I have created VFs over PFs and used them for binding to DPDK, which was causing the issue. Now used PFs itself and solved the problem.